# Which sentence is more appropriate?

Tags: sentence-construction

I am writing an article. I want to select a suitable sentence for the part of my article. Assume that there are N tasks, T<sub>1</sub> through T<sub>N</sub>, located on a processor. Every task T<sub>i</sub> has an attribute--let me call it *k<sub>i</sub>*.

Now, after my introduction of a formula such as **X = k<sub>i</sub> + Y**, I want to immediately write about **k<sub>i</sub>** after the formula. Which of the following sentences is more appropriate?

> X = k<sub>i</sub> + Y; *where* k<sub>i</sub> *is an attribute for the tasks located in order i on the processor.*
>   X = k<sub>i</sub> + Y; *where* k<sub>i</sub> *is an attribute for the tasks located in sequence i on the processor.*
>   [...]

Comment: _Where ki is an attribute for the tasks in the sequence of i elements_

Comment: I think saying "`ki` is an attribute of task `Ti`" is possible, but it is better to say what the attribute is explicitly. For example, if `k` is an expected execution time, you can write, "where `ki` is *the* expected execution time of task `Ti`".

Comment: @ Damkerng T. Thank you for editing my question. Specially the part " Assume that there are N tasks, T1 through TN". I have changed this part in my article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscript *i* is neither an order nor a sequence; it is an index into an order or a sequence.  Therefore referring to "order *i*" or "sequence *i*" is incorrect.

Something like

> Where k<sub>i</sub> is an attribute of the task T<sub>i</sub> on the processor

or

> where k<sub>i</sub> is an attribute of the task at position *i*

would be much better.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I think your first sequence and also Damkerng's sequence are OK but they cannot be appropriate for my article because of some details that I do not mention them in my question. But I accept your second sentence